# RStudio --> Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, text-classification

But I am working in RStudio. and facing the below error related with Keras & Tensorflow.

Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:/Users/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/python36.dll
pythonhome:     C:/Users/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.10 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, May  7 2020, 19:46:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:/Users/AppData/Local/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/Lib/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.18.5

Any help on this is very appreciable.

Comment: Also Note:: I have worked on below solution but nothing is working for me. 

install.packages("devtools") devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras") library(keras) install_tensorflow() install_tensorflow(gpu=TRUE)  devtools::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow") devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")

Comment: For running a python code a Python IDE, like Pycharm would easier to use. I'm not sure whether RStudio can install Python packages as it is mainly for R. But you can install it from the miniconda installation, I'm sure. Something like "conda install keras" or so.

Comment: "conda install keras" command will work in Anaconda promp i.e. for Pythont. But for R coding, Even I have tried installing both Keras and Tensor flow, both are even reflecting also under installed R libraries. But when I am running the code "model_cnn <- keras_model_sequential()". It is throwing me the below error.

Error: Python module tensorflow.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:....

Comment: Approach2:
I have tried below approach as well but no luck.

install.packages("devtools")
require(devtools)
install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
install_github("rstudio/keras")
library(reticulate)
library(tensorflow)
library(keras)
model_k = keras_model_sequential()
Error: Installation of TensorFlow not found.

Python environments searched for 'tensorflow' package:
 C:\Users\abc\AppData\Local\r-miniconda\envs\r-reticulate\python.exe

You can install TensorFlow using the install_tensorflow() function.

Comment: I am having the same issue on Window 10. Have you found the solution?